# remove margin between bootstrap form inputs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using bootstrap to display a form-inline. However, I cannot figure how to remove the spaces between the form inputs, it always leaves a ~4p blank. I tried to adjust it using margin, in vain. Any idea why ?

Here's the form

```
<div class="container">
<form id="msform" class="form-inline" role="form" method="post">
  <!-- progressbar -->
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" id="form_departure" name="form[departure]" required="required" placeholder="Départ" class="form-control"><input type="text" id="autocompleter_form_departure" name="autocompleter_form[departure]" required="required" placeholder="Départ" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" id="form_arrival" name="form[arrival]" required="required" placeholder="Arrivée" class="form-control"><input type="text" id="autocompleter_form_arrival" name="autocompleter_form[arrival]" required="required" placeholder="Arrivée" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <select id="form_passengers" name="form[passengers]" required="required" class="fly_confirm form-control"><option value="1" selected="selected">1 passager</option><option value="2">2 passagers</option><option value="3">3 passagers</option><option value="4">4 passagers</option><option value="5">5 passagers</option></select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">CHERCHER</button>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: My apologies, just did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline elements are sensitive to the white space in your code. The easiest solution is to simply remove it.

Ex: `</div><div class="form-group">`

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/PTfs1SfIuY)**

An alternative is to float the inputs:

```
.form-group {
   float:left; 
}
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/It0Oqx1Gva)**

Comment: indeed, this was because of the spaces in code ! Thank you very much.